# Fibonacci Sequence Analogue (Using Multiplication, Rather Than Addition)

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, products

Define a sequence $J_n$ such that $J_1=1/2$, $J_2=k$, and $$J_n=\prod_{m=1}^{n-1} J_m$$ Determine, if it exists, the value of $k$ for which $J_n$ goes to 1 as $n$ tends to infinity.

What if $J_1$ is given an arbitrary value other than $1/2$? Is there then a way to determine the value of $J_2$ such that $J_n$ goes to 1 as $n$ tends to infinity?

Comment: You realise that for $n\ge4$ we have $J_n=J_{n-1}J_{n-2}$?

Comment: Oh, wait - is the problem statement correct? As it stands, $J_3=J_1$???

Comment: In what way is this the analogue of Fibonacci ?

Comment: As Hagen von Eitzen mentions in his answer, we have a Fibonacci-like recurrence. Specifically, $J_{n+1}=J_n J_{n-1}$.

Comment: @LieutenantZipp: I mentioned that this is wrong. I now understand that it is because you edited the question in a wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\frac{J_{n+1}}{J_n}=\frac{\prod_{m=1}^{n}J_m}{\prod_{m=1}^{n-1}J_m} =J_{n-1},$$
so we have the Fibonacci-like recurrence
$$J_{n+1}=J_nJ_{n-1}$$
and so 
$$\log_2 J_{n+1}=\log_2 J_n +\log_2 J_{n-1}.$$
We have $\log_2J_1=-1$ and want to determine $\log_2J_2$ so that $\log_2J_n\to 0$.
It is well.known that 
$$ \log_2 J_n=c_+\cdot\lambda_+^n+c_-\lambda_-^n$$
where $\lambda_{\pm}=\frac{1\pm\sqrt 5}{2}$ and $c_{\pm}$ are determined by the first two terms via the equations
$$\begin{align}\log_2J_1&=c_+\lambda_++c_-\lambda_-\\\log_2J_2&=c_+\lambda_+^2+c_-\lambda_-^2\end{align} $$ Hence we have $\log_2J_n\to 0$ iff $c_+=0$, in other words, iff
$$ \log_2J_2=\lambda_-\cdot\log_2J_1.$$
With $\log_2J_1=-1$ given, we need
$$ J_2=2^{-\frac{1-\sqrt 5}{2}}\approx 1.53478225382648941.$$

Comment: I don't agree with your first identity, should be $J_n$ on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Let us first determine a closed form for $J_n$. With some work we arrive at
$$ J_n = \frac{k^{F_{n-2}}}{2^{F_{n-3}}}$$
where $F_n$ denotes the $n$-th Fibonacci number ($F_0 = 1, F_1 = 1, F_2 = 2$ etc)

For $J_n$ to be one we want $k^{F_{n-2}} = 2^{F_{n-3}}$, or $k = 2^{\frac{F_{n-3}}{F_{n-2}}}$. As $n$ goes to infinity, this tends to $2^{1/\varphi}$ where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio.

This shows that (check) if we take $k = 2^{1/\varphi}$ then $J_n = 2^{ F_{n-2} / \varphi - F_{n-3}}$ so tends to $2^0 = 1$.

Comment: This is a great solution, but unfortunately I made a slight error in the statement of the problem, and you solved the problem I didn’t mean to ask, but accidentally asked anyway. Sorry about that.

Comment: Oh, that is fine. I think the solution still works if I shift the indices a bit. Let me try.

Comment: @LieutenantZipp Actually your fix made me find an error. I think my solution works now, and the answer remains the same (but now correctly so).