# Multiplicative Fibonacci sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-number-theory, reference-request, fibonacci-numbers

The famous Fibonacci sequence is defined by the recurrence relation $$F_n=F_{n-1}+F_{n-2}$$ where $F_n$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ term of the sequence. What if instead of adding the previous two terms, we multiply them? So the recurrence relation becomes $$F_n^*=F_{n-1}^*×F_{n-2}^*$$ where $F_n^*$ is the $n^{\text{th}}$ term of the sequence. The usual initial terms $0$ and $1$ gives a boring sequence, but other initial terms like $2$ and $3$ gives something better.

Now what kind of properties would this sequence have? When I tried googling it, I had only found this [math paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/233236394_Fibonacci%27s_multiplicative_sequence) and this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3268807/fibonacci-sequence-analogue-using-multiplication-rather-than-addition). Is there any other information about this?

Comment: Look a [this](https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C3%2C6%2C18%2C108&language=french&go=Chercher).

Comment: Just take the logarithm to get an additive Fibonacci-like sequence again. – See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3314911/42969 about the Fibonacci sequence with arbitrary start values.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe Thanks for mentioning it. I had seen that before, but forgot to mention

Comment: Just keep count of the exponents of $2$ and $3$: $F_n^* = 2^{F_{n-1}}3^{F_n}$. Did you even try a little to solve the problem?

Comment: @jjagmath Yes, I had noticed that. This is not a problem, I just asked for some interesting properties. I had found some properties myself too.

Comment: @HishamShefeekh Then you should share your findings instead of expecting others to redo your work.